# asyncpg - Connect to server and create database if not exists

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, asyncpg

Is there a way to create a database in a PostgreSQL server using asyncpg like you can in Hibernate, using:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

flags in the uri. Is there a way to connect to the server without connecting to a db and execute sql statements?

Answer (score 7):

There is no shortcut for this in asyncpg, but it's easy to implement in your code.  Every PostgreSQL cluster has a `template1` database, which can be used to issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement if the original database you are connecting to does not exist.  `CREATE DATABASE` usually requires special privileges, so you need to use a superuser account when connecting to `template1` (usually `postgres`).

Example:

```py
import asyncio
import asyncpg

async def connect_create_if_not_exists(user, database):
    try:
        conn = await asyncpg.connect(user=user, database=database)
    except asyncpg.InvalidCatalogNameError:
        # Database does not exist, create it.
        sys_conn = await asyncpg.connect(
            database='template1',
            user='postgres'
        )
        await sys_conn.execute(
            f'CREATE DATABASE "{database}" OWNER "{user}"'
        )
        await sys_conn.close()

        # Connect to the newly created database.
        conn = await asyncpg.connect(user=user, database=database)

    return conn


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    connect_create_if_not_exists(user='elvis', database='new-database')
)
```

Comment: Thank you, got to the same solution without the 
` asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    connect_create_if_not_exists(user='elvis', database='new-database')
) `
part